# Как сделать Distinct по длине строки?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список

```
текст;99999
текст фывфы;99999
```

Я хочу получить уникальные позиции по второй части от разделителя `;`. В данном случае это число `99999`

Никак не могу найти решение для моей задачи. Написал решение на псевдокоде

```
var rez = list.DistinctByWhere(x=>x.Split(';')[0].Length.IsMax)
```

В результате должно остаться в списке только

```
текст;99999
```

Comment: не понял при чём тут длинна строки. пример лучше привести там где элементов побольше

Comment: а какой результат брать если вначале строки стоят разные токены? почему в вашем результате первую выбрал строчку а не вторую?

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, сравнение происходит не по *длине*, а по *значению* второй части расщепленной строки, так?

Если я правильно понял условие, то нужно создать компаратор:

```
class SplitComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var left = x.Split(';')[1];
        var right = y.Split(';')[1];
        return left == right;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        var end = obj.Split(';')[1];
        return end.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var result = list.Distinct(new SplitComparer());
```

Это неэффективно, т. к. сплит происходит два раза, но на скорую руку ничего лучше не придумал.

Конечно, нужно сделать дополнительные проверки в коде или перехват возможных исключений.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `Distinct` всегда можно воспользоваться группировкой, а затем взять из каждой группы один (первый) элемент. Это будет выглядеть короче, но, скорее всего, менее эффективно:

```
string[] lines = { "текст;99999", "текст фывфы;99999" };
var result = lines.GroupBy(line => line.Split(';')[1]).Select(g => g.First());
```

---

На самом деле вы не должны работать с таким строками, если одна такая строка представляет собой некий объект, то создайте класс и работайте с полноценными объектами:

```
class MyData
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    // Другие свойства ...

    public static MyData Parse(string s)
    {
        var parts = s.Split(';');
        return new MyData
        {
            StringProperty = parts[0],
            IntProperty = int.Parse(parts[1]),
            // Другие свойства ...
        };
    }
}
```

Теперь просто один раз распарсите свои строки в объекты и работайте с коллекцией объектов:

```
var data = lines.Select(MyData.Parse).ToList();
```

если уникальность объектов вашего класса определяется уникальностью одного или нескольких его свойств, то переопределите `Equals` и `GetHashCode` в своем классе, это позволит вызывать `Distinct` вообще без параметров

иначе — создайте классы, реализующие `IEqualityComparer<MyData>`, наподобие как в соседнем ответе, либо пользуйтесь группировкой, либо подключите библиотеку [morelinq из NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) и воспользуйтесь методом-расширения [`DistinctBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.9/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_DistinctBy__2.htm) из ее состава